# WordPress - Maintaining two /wp-admin/ sites on one server

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I am trying to setup two WordPress-sites on the same server. One is for live usage, the other is for development. Both should have completely independent Databases, so I can try some long-term upgrades on the dev site.

I want to be able to login into `www.example_url.com/wp-admin/` and separate from that into `www.example_url.com/dev/wp-admin/`. I can go to `www.example_url.com/dev/wp-login.php` and login, but then I get redirected (and logged in) to `www.example_url.com/wp-admin/` with the wrong database.

So far, I have copied the WordPress folder to `example_url.com/sandbox/`, changed the `wp-config.php` of the new folder, so I have independent databases and I changed `/etc/httpd/conf.d/example_url.com.vhost_common`. In there I added an alias: `Alias /dev "home/httpd/www.exampl_url.com/sandbox"`.

Comment: Great question, maybe provide some snapshots of the configuration files that you have changed.